# Is Google analytics available for Phonegap

Tags: cordova, google-analytics

For my phonegap app, there is actually only one page, the index.html, which is an empty one. All other pages are loaded via ajax calls into the index.html. I want to use google analytics for all ajax views. Is it possible?

What's more, there is no "click" events in my app, as I used touchstart, touchmove, touchend to handle clicks. I wonder if google analytics can work without clicking, touching instead. (as I remember, google analytics can record clicking data for each links)

In summary, my problems are:

1. window.location doesn't change due to all views are loaded via ajax;
2. no click events

Will I be able to use google analytics for my PhoneGap app? Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a [Google Analytics plugin](http://phonegap.com/2011/05/04/phonegap-alytics/) you can use for your PhoneGap app.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use ga.js within phonegap without a plugin then you can use this
https://github.com/ggendre/GALocalStorage